# OSX ML, Other.. account appeared after installation

Tags: macos, user-accounts

On OSX Mountain Lion, an Other... account has appeared after installing [this](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php) application. Later I uninstalled the application and also removed the Other... account from accounts list in Users & Groups, but it still remains visible in log in screen. I followed few guides on how to remove it but they didnt work. I do not have access to the Other... account, and also followed the instructions for uninstalling the application that caused this correctly. Any suggestions?

p.s. On terminal when I execute dscl . -ls /Users the last accounts that appear are:

```
daemon
Guest
ioannislatousakis
nobody
nxhttpd
root
```

**UPDATE**
I just realised I can log in the Other.. account using my default account name/pass. Still dont know how to remove it though.

**UPDATE 2**
The log in screen went back to normal, although today I found another crazy thing. NoMachine appears in microphone options in QuickTime player. What should I do for a throughout uninstall?

[image]

Comment: If may just be some open directory dirty cache left by the nx uninstall. 2 easy things to try. (1) Reboot (2) Safe boot, instruction: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11212.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Other..." often shows when there is a user which is not a daemon, yet it is not quite a regular GUI user. Quite often that is "root" user.

If that is the case, do the following: Make sure you have another user with admin privileges on the system, and then try to Disable the root user according to instructions at [the related Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11331?viewlocale=en_US).

Comment: Nope, root is disabled..

Comment: How about that nxhttpd user? It seems to be nxmachine application-related. If you know it is not related to other software you have, rid of it. You can `dscl . -read /Users/nxhttpd` to look at it and similarly delete it (see the dscl man page, will likely need to use sudo). Also, it will not remove the user from whatever groups the software created. You may want to use `dscl . -readall /Groups` to see what else needs to be cleaned. Now, given the messiness they left behind, did you try to solicit the uninstall instructions from them? May be ping them on twitter @NXfollowers?

Comment: Here is the terminal output from the commands you suggested.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6j6ilgijbwfr0g8/PZ99eLrhjF
On the readAll /Groups I get nx only once.

Comment: deleting the nxhttpd did the trick although nx still appears in readAll group on one entry:

AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: 60E3547E-FB3E-43EB-84CE-9A641F8546CE
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 403
RealName: NXHttpd group
RecordName: nxhttpd
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups

Comment: Glad it worked for you. To delete the group, you can `sudo dscl . -delete /Groups/nxhttpd`

Comment: As a side note, your case was a clear cut. Whoever reads this question later should be very careful as manipulating directory services directly like that can do a lot of harm.

Comment: Vlad any ideas on how to solve the issue in update 2? also twitted nomachine.

Comment: It is likely in the file: `/Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist` - but I have no idea of the implications of editing the file. *MAKE BACKUP* of it before any changes. You may have to edit the file manually - `vi` or similar, as the system plist editor does not show all entries on my system.

Comment: So that people will see the question as unanswered and give some attention. Its not that important any more as I will be changing my SSD soon and Ill make a clean install. THanks for all the help.